# GAE Golang - OAuth and OAuth2?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, go

I'm trying to implement a Google App Engine Go application that will be using OAuth and OAuth2 for users logging in. I'm wondering if it is possible, and if so, how to do it? Can someone provide an example of this?

Comment: Do you want to call an external API using OAuth2? Or implement a OAuth2 provider for your application?

Comment: @proppy I want to let the users log in on my website with such OAuth providers as Facebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [goauth2](http://code.google.com/p/goauth2/) to implement an OAuth2 client on App Engine

You can then log your users with their Google Account by requesting `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` scopes as shown on [Using OAuth 2.0 for Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login)